# Is there a very simple way to construct a uniformly distributed sequence of reals on $[0, 1]$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Is there a very simple way to construct a uniformly distributed sequence of reals on $[0, 1]$, i.e. does not invoke Weyl equidistribution theorem?

Comment: An enumeration of the rationals?

Comment: I was about to say that: what about $0.5,0.25,0.75,0.125,0.375,0.625,0.875,...$?

Comment: In other words, a sequence of finite binary expansion of increasing length, where all the numbers of a certain length are listed before adding another digit.